# BeautifulSoup not found after installing via pip

Tags: python, pip

I am using *Homebrew* to install python on Snow Leopard.

After installing python (2.7.2), I add `/usr/local/share/python` to the front of my `PATH`. I also set `PYTHONPATH` to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

If I use `pip` to install *lxml* or *feedparser*, for example, then after running `python`, I can `import lxml` with no issue.

After running `pip install BeautifulSoup`, there exists a `.egg-info` directory for BeautifulSoup in the `site-packages` directory listed above, as well as the `bs4` directory, but `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` just gives me an error in the python interpreter.

`sys.path` is:

```
['', 
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg', 
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg', 
 '/Users/Chris/src/python-pinboard', 
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python27.zip', 
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7', 
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', 
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', 
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', 
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Any idea what's going on?

#### Update: Solution Found

By default, latest BeautifulSoup, 4.0b, gets installed. Use stable release, `pip install BeautifulSoup==3.2.0`, and importing etc. works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, latest BeautifulSoup, 4.0b, gets installed. Use stable release, `pip install BeautifulSoup==3.2.0`, and importing etc. works.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is now splitted into `beautifulsoup` (version 3.*.*) and `beautifulsoup4` (version 4.*.*) in pip.

So to install a specific version run:

```
sudo pip install beautifulsoup # version 3
```

or

```
sudo pip install beautifulsoup4 # version 4
```